# How to add rel="nofollow" and target="_blank" in this wordpress shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am planning to change the wordpress theme of my site. The theme allows me to add the social icons in sidebars and in other positions of the site using the shortcode option provided in the theme. But I want to add rel="nofollow" in the beginning and target="_blank" at the end of resulted URL.

Here is the code which I found in one of the theme files.

```
// [social_icon src="" title="Add a hover title!" link="#custom-link"]
function social_icon_sc($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'src' => 'picons33.png',
        'title' => __('Get in touch'),
        'link' => '#'
    ), $atts));

    $output = "";

    $output .= "<a href='".$link."' class='social-icon' title='".$title."'>";
    $output .= "<img src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/social_icons/".$src."' alt='".$title."' />";
    $output .= "</a>";

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('social_icon', 'social_icon_sc');
```

Could any one please tell me how to add nofollow and target_blank in the URL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line

```
$output .= "<a href='".$link."' class='social-icon' title='".$title."'>";
```

to

```
$output .= "<a rel='nofollow' href='".$link."' class='social-icon' title='".$title."' target='_blank'>";
```